# Can't get element in Chrome Dev Tools unless I inspect it manually

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I wanna retrive a table in this page,and do something

however I cant getElementById directly in console before I use chrome inspecter to select it.

**I cant access to the source code**
so what should i do?

following screenshot show my issue

> Cannot access to
>   [image: cannot access to]
>
> Use Chrome Inspector and clicked on the page .now I cant get this element
>   [image: can access it now]

Comment: Is it in a frame? click the `top` and select the correct location of where the element is located. You can see in your second screenshot is not top.

Comment: In case someone is still struggling with the reason behind this, i found this answer really helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44018158/6217195

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first screenshot your console selector is "top", in your second screenshot the selector is "zhuti(content.aspx)" - that could indicate that element is not accessible in top document (maybe it is in an iframe?)

It would be helpful if you provide html or link to source page.

Comment: Just post sourcePage directly ,what a mess,Forgive me--------------------------<div>
      <iframe id="iframeautoheight" class="rightcontiframe" name="zhuti" allowtransparency src="content.aspx"
       scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload="javascript:dyniframesize('iframeautoheight');"></iframe>
     </div>
</pre>

Comment: Thanks for  ur help ,have figured it out------document.getElementById('iframeautoheight').contentWindow.document.getElementById('DataGrid1')

Comment: No problem, glad you found it.

Answer (score 8):

If you look at your screenshot, when it is undefined, it is top.
When you select it, the selection changes to content.aspx

So that means the element resides inside of an iframe/frame. So you would need to change it to point to the correct element.

[image]