# Javascript getelementbyid returning null unless inspect element

Tags: javascript, iframe, javascript-objects

When I try to get the element via

```
document.getElementById('rc-anchor-container')
```

it returns null.

However when I inspect the page for elements, and running the same code above it will return something.

From what I read, it's because of the iframe.

[Can't get element in Chrome Dev Tools unless I inspect it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428105/cant-get-element-in-chrome-dev-tools-unless-i-inspect-it-manually/40428234)

Therefore, I tried the solution:

```
document.querySelector('[title="iframeTitle"]').contentWindow.document
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
VM11054:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://somedomain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:60
```

How do I get the element by id in this case?

Comment: Well you are are being blocked by the same origin policy

Comment: What can I do in this case? Is there a way for me to load the content using javascript, considering I can inspect element, run the same code and then it works? @epascarello

Comment: Because the console is probably set to the iframe after you inspect it.